# Limit numbers of login

Tags: php, authentication, limit

I want to create the limit login based on the udid of the devices. For example users only can login with 2 different devices at the same time. this what i did, but is not working to lock the 3rd users when login

```
    // Get the email and password
$email       = CParam::paramPost('email');
$firstpassword    = CParam::paramPost('password');
$password    = md5(CParam::paramPost('password'));
$udid        = CParam::paramPost('udid');
$app_id      = CParam::paramPost('app_id');
$app_version = CParam::paramPost('app_version');

// Make sure we have a UDID
if (empty($udid)) {
    sendJsonError('UDID parameter is missing');
    return;
}

// Check if the user is entitled
$sql    = 'SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE email = :email AND password = :password';
$params = array('email' => $email, 'password' => $password);
$account   = $db->fetchOne($sql, $params);
if (!$account) {
    sendJsonError('We could not find your subscription.');
    return;
}

// The account was found, generate an successs token if not existing yet
if (empty($account['success_token'])) {
    $success_token = CGuid::create();
    $db->update(
        'accounts',
        array('success_token' => $success_token),
        'id = :id',
        array('id' => $account['id'])
    );
} else {
    $success_token = $account['success_token'];
}

// Register the device
$db->insertOrUpdate(
    'devices',
    array(
        'account_id'  => $account['id'],
        'udid'        => $udid,
        'app_id'      => $app_id,
        'app_version' => $app_version,
    )
);
```

Thanks

Comment: Sidenote: I hope you're intending on using a safer password hash than MD5, once such as `password_hash()`.

Comment: Hi, there is no condition in your code that would check how many success_tokens have user generated.. or is the condition elswhere?

Comment: Hi @Jimmmy, no, i am not yet created conditions. still trying to find how to write condition tutorial over the web, but no one works yet, can you please advice?

Comment: well in theory, you have to store one unique identificator of login (session id would suffice), and one identificator of user whose login it was (user id) and save it somewhere (db?). So with new login you check number of registered (and valid in time) sessions for the user and alow/deny this user to log based on count..